# How to set an nonexistent field in Python ClientForm?

Tags: python, mechanize, clientform

I'm using mechanize (which uses clientform) for some web crawling in python and since it doesn't support JS, I want to set a value of an unexistent input in a form (the input is generated by JS). How can I do this?

The error is similar to the one you get if you try to execute

```
from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()
page = br.open('http://google.com')
br.select_form(nr = 0)
br['unexistent'] = 'hello'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to first add the control to the form, and then `fixup` the form.

```
br.form.new_control('text','unexistent',{'value':''})
br.form.fixup()
br['unexistent'] = 'hello'
```

This really isn't very well documented, and in the source under `fixup()` there is the comment:

```
This method should only be called once, after all controls have been
added to the form.
```

However, it doesn't look like it does anything too dangerous. Probably at least add the control first before messing with anything else in the form.